# How to make update on session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I bring signers information.When updating There is a problem.

Here my code:

```
 OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.mdb"));
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    baglanti.Open();
    var ID = Session["id"];
    OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("select *from tablo1 where id=" + ID + "", baglanti);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", TextBox6.Text);
    OleDbDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();

    if (oku.Read())
    {
        TextBox1.Text = oku["isim"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = oku["soyisim"].ToString();
        TextBox3.Text = oku["kadi"].ToString();
        TextBox4.Text = oku["sifre"].ToString();
        TextBox5.Text = oku["email"].ToString();
    }
}
```

and,

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //update
    var ID = Session["id"];
    OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("update tablo1 set isim=@isim,soyisim=@soyisim,kadi=@kadi,sifre=@sifre,email=@email  where id=" + ID + "", baglanti);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isim", TextBox1.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soyisim", TextBox2.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kadi", TextBox3.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", TextBox4.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox5.Text);
    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
    baglanti.Close();
}
```

Not updating.I am selecting datas.But Button1_Click doesnt working.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really sory I didn't read the post carefully 
Add following code at the first of pageload event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your problem is how to update session or Button1_Click not working

so her this

> > to update Session use ( Session["id"] = theNewValue; )
> >
> > for button event not prevented pleas paste here the button tag from design page

Comment: I am changing the value, but the butona press comes back with the old value.So not updated.